# How to leave the last two strings of the path?

Tags: javascript, string, split, path

I have urls that I need to keep only the last two strings between slashes.

For ex,
`/first/second/third/` want to have `/second/third/` or `/first/second/third/fourth/` want to have `/third/fourth/`.
I think use `regex`, but wonder if it's faster then `split`.

What is the better way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go the split route, you might have to do some splicing together of the various components.  You could try a regex split, but I might go for regex match here:

```js
var input = "/first/second/third/fourth/";
var output = input.match(/(?:\/[^\/]+){2}\/$/)[0];
console.log(output);
```